# How can I change the opaque property of a div from 0% to 100% top to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have a web site with a fixed height black header like the one used here:

https://elementsproject.org/posts/

Notice how when a user scrolls the page the black text hits the black header. As the white background page with black text **scrolls to the top** I would like the black text color to fade away. In other words what I would like to do is to have a header bottom border with a white color where the opaqueness (is that a word) goes from 100% to zero.

Can someone tell me how I can make the opaque property change in this way from top to bottom of the header strip? Note that I'm looking for a modern browser solution only so that might make it a bit easier.

Thanks

Comment: @Harry - I updated my question to make it a bit more clear.  Hope that helps.  No need to animate as I would like the user scrolling the page to see the black text color change to white before it hits the bottom of the black header. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use a box-shadow or a linear-gradient for this.

/* filled 50/50 */

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#yourBackgroundColorHere, transparent);
```

/* just the last 25% */

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#yourBackgroundColorHere 75%, transparent);
```

for more information check CSS-Tricks.com https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

/* just a box-shadow under your header */

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px #yourBackgroundColorHere;
```

for more information about box-shadow check CSS-Tricks.com https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

--
**disclaimer:** I'm not affiliated with css-tricks.com in any way, it is just a great website about everything css

Answer (score 0):

try this code in style

```
100%
div { opacity: 0.0; }
50%
div { opacity: 0.5; }
0%
div { opacity: 1.0; }
```

for animation in jquery

```
$("#DivID").animate({opacity: 0}, 5000); //5 sec transaction
```